# How to pass props in Link in react-Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router, router

I have a hotel's page and **I want to create a Page for each single hotel**.
How could I pass props in Link in react-Router?
And how can I use it in my hotel Component?

Comment: i use react-hooks

Answer (score 0):

you can add params to the link

```
<Link 
  to={{
     pathname: "/path/to/",
     state:{...props}
  }}> 
></Link>
```

use it like that

```
const params = this.props.location.state
```

Comment: can i pass object ?

Comment: @MouazALbari yes, btw what params are u want to pass

Comment: pass hotel object

Comment: match is undefinde

Comment: in your  hotel Component console the `props.location.state`

Answer (score 0):

React Router's `<Link>` component will decorate any component (or an anchor `<a>` tag) with routing functionality, passing any extra prop you provide. From its documentation, you can see how it ends up rendering the component.

[Here is a link to the source code](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js)

Any extra prop you define on the body of the `<Link>` React Router will pass to the provided component or anchor tag. You could do something like this:

*Using the default `<Link>` component:*

```js
const hotels = [{id: 1, name: 'hotel 1'}, {id: 2, name: 'hotel 2'}]

function LinkList({hotels}) {
  return (
    hotels.map(hotel => <Link to={`/hotel/${id}`} hotel={hotel} /> 
  )
}
```

**Using a custom component*:**

```js
const FancyLink = React.forwardRef(({hotel, ...props}, ref) => (
  <a ref={ref} {...props}>{hotel.name} {props.children}</a>
))

function LinkList({hotels}) {
  return (
    hotels.map(hotel => <FancyLink to={`/hotel/${id}`} hotel={hotel} /> 
  )
}
```

`*` Taken from [React Router's docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/component-reactcomponent)